# Why isn't sys.stdout.flush() printing all the characters on the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, flush, sys

Here's my code:

```
wait = "..."
for char in wait:
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(1)
   print(char)
```

I'm trying to get it to ouput:

```
...
```

But instead it outputs:

```
.
.
.
```

I don't understand why sys.stdout.flush has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `help(print)` in the Python interpreter, you'll get:

> ```
> print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
> Optional keyword arguments:
> file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
> sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
> end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
> flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
> ```

Using this information:

```
for char in wait:
   time.sleep(1)
   print(char, end='', flush=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

`std.out.flush()` just writes whats in the buffer onto the screen

By default, `print()` adds a `\n` to the end to write a new line. You can turn it off by doing `print(s, end='')`

Answer (score 0):

Using parameter `end=''` in `print` you can achieve the desired results:
Try out this:

```
import sys
import time
wait = "..."
for char in wait:
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(1)
   print(char, end='')
```

You can read more about the `end` parameter [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
import time

wait = "..."
for char in wait:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(char, end="", file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
```